# overfull vbox with beamercolorbox

Tags: beamer, spacing, warnings

In a latex-beamer document, I am using a custom headline template. It produces a headline *only* when in a section. Here is a stripped down version:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{times} % gets rid of fontsize warnings
\setbeamercolor{section in head}{bg=yellow!80!black,fg=structure} 
%% \setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=yellow!50!black}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
   \ifx\insertsection\empty\else
   \usebeamerfont{section in head}
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2ex,dp=1ex,leftskip=2ex]{section in head}
     \insertsection 
   \end{beamercolorbox}
   %%\begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.5pt]{lower separation line head}\end{beamercolorbox}
   \fi
   \vspace*{5pt}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  % frame has empty headline
\end{frame}
 \section{A Section}
\begin{frame}
  % frame headline shows section title
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, this code produces an "overfull vbox": `Overfull \vbox (9.41396pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []`

I could ignore it because the result looks fine, but I'd like to know why this is happening and how I could deal with it, mostly because it is irritatint to see this printed out over 200 times.

(Note: this does not happen when commenting out lines 6 and 12, the ones with \if and \fi.)

Comment: This is indeed very funny. In my tests the `\ifx .. \fi` also causes the overfull vbox warning and I can't really see or understand why. I tried some variations but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the line 5 to say:

```
 \ifx\insertsection\empty\hrule height2ex depth1ex width0pt\else
```

I believe that what happens is beamer calculates the total height of the head at the beginning of the document, before `\insertsection` is set, and uses this value to calculate the other dimensions of the page.  With the head empty, it expects the size of the head to be 0, and if the head is not empty, the whole page is overfull.  Notice that on the pages with the section head, with the original code, the navigation line is pushed out of the page, so it disappears.

Comment: That seems to work! So apparently, beamer can't deal with headlines of variable height (in the sense that it cannot be predicted without parsing the entire document).

Comment: During my tests I was using `\vskip 9.41396pt` instead of this `2ex+1ex`, any reason this would be the exact size? Or is it just a fair over-approximation?

Answer (score 1):

Put `\vspace*{-9.41396pt}` before the `\fi`.

Comment: Do you know why it is caused by the `\ifx .. \fi`?

Comment: @Martin No idea.

Comment: Thank you, at least now I can compile without warnings. But it's not the most definitive solution I guess.

Comment: That's _cheating_! :)

Comment: Also, it has the disadvantage that if there is a lower separation line `\begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.5pt]{lower separation line head}\end{beamercolorbox}` to seperate headline from normal text, it will not be placed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `\ifx\insertsection\undefined\else` <strike>might be more appropriate here.</strike> (no, see comments) And it solves the warning issue. I can't tell what's happening with `\empty` though.

Comment: Yes, it "solves" the issue because the conditional is always false, so it's equivalent to not putting the conditional at all. But the OP doesn't want the colored band when the section title has not yet been set.

Comment: Hmm, right I thought `\insertsection` was user supplied, but it's some beamer command. Looking at the code I can't understand what's going on… looks like beamer does multiple passes: using `\ifx\insertsection\empty\vskip 30pt\else` we can see that the 'non-else' part is taken into account even if the 'else' part is the displayed one.